# Change style of Segmented Control in code

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-5

I'm developing an app, and to make use of the extra space in the iPhone 5 screen, I would like to change the style of this `UISegmentedControl`. So, this involve two parts. First, detect in code if it's an iPhone 5 and then change the style.

In the 3.5" it will be this style

[image: bar]

And in the 4" this.

[image: plain]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the size of the screen using `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]`. If bounds.size.height is bigger than some number (you decide what that would be) then set the segmented control's `segmentedControlStyle` property.  For larger height you want `UISegmentedControlStylePlain`.  For other, you want `UISegmentedControlStyleBar`.